# run isotope callback after media loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jplayer

I am looping through all the .jplayer classes on my page and then for each found class, making an ajax call which returns the urls of each song associated with the player. I want to wait until all the ajax calls are complete and and all success callbacks executed (i.e., all jplayer instances are instantiated) and then run isotope on my container element.

I have initially tried to run isotope as a callback of my loadTracks method, but this does not work because the ajax calls return before all players are instantiated. This causes problems when isotope is attempting to determine the layout of the page since each player can have varying heights.

Here is my current code which retrieves the player tracks:

```
            function loadTracks(players, callback) {
            players.each(function(i,elem) {
                var playerId = $(this).attr('id'),
                    arr = playerId.split('_'),
                    postId = arr[2];

            $.ajax({
                    url: BaseHref + "api/v1/Post/" + postId + '/PostTracks',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var cssSelector = {
                            jPlayer: '#jquery_jplayer_' + postId,
                            cssSelectorAncestor: '#jp_container_' + postId
                        }
                        var playlist = [];
                        makePlaylist = (function() {
                            $.each(data.data, function(index,value) {
                                playlist.push({
                                    title: value['Title'],
                                    m4a: value['m4aURL'],
                                    ogg: value['oggURL']
                                });
                            });

                        })();


                        var options = {
                            swfPath: BaseHref + 'themes/simple/javascript/jplayer',
                            supplied: 'm4a, oga',
                            displayTime: 0,
                            addTime: 0,
                            removeTime: 0,
                            shuffleTime: 0,
                            enableRemoveControls: true
                        };
                        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

                    }
                });
            });
            callback();
        }
```

Then I run:

```
loadTracks($('.jp-jplayer'), function() {
            $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector : selector,
                    transformsEnabled: false,
                    visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 },
                    hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 },
                    resizable: false,
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: setColumns($container),
                        gutterWidth: 10
                    },
                    getSortData: {
                        date: function ( $elem ) {
                        return $elem.data('date');  
                        }
                    },
                    sortBy: 'date',
                    sortAscending: false
                });
            });
            if ( $('#overlay').length ) setTimeout(function() { $('#overlay').fadeOut(); }, 1000);
        })
```

How can I execute the isotope method on my container only after all the ajax calls in my $.each loop have returned and all jplayer instances have been instantiated via the success methods?